# Fetch Metadata from Salesforce using Tooling API objects

Tags: soql, metadata-api, java, tooling-api

I am building a tool in Java to fetch all the metadata from Salesforce using the Tooling API.

For Ex: I want to fetch all the profiles details including object-permission, field-premission, recordtype settings, tab setting etc. using Tooling API.

Can anyone suggest me how to fetch all these details using Tooling API?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the [Tooling API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm), and do you have a specific issue in mind? Right now, your question is broad enough that it's hard to answer beyond simply linking to the documentation.

Comment: yes i gone thorugh the Tooling API documentation. Is there any tooling api object available to fetch objectpermission, fieldlevelpermissoin etc. so that I can use https://instancename.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/tooling/query?******

Comment: @DavidReed is right. That's basically the whole API. What are you having trouble with? Determining how to make the query? The authentication?

Comment: Yes..My question is how to make query to fetch all profile metadata including object permission, field permisssion, record type etc.